# Eclipse can't find Web Resource

Tags: java, eclipse

In Luna Eclipse I am getting an error `undefined JavaScript file ("resources/js/services.js")` in my HTML file.
Everything work perfect in the browser, it is just Eclipse not able to find the resource files (JavaScript and CSS).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since I saw your project contains a pom.xml, so I suppose you are using the MAVEN. If you usingthe maven to generate the job, just do a  "mvn clean:clean" and "mvn eclipse:eclipse" by using terminator or cmd cd to your project folder.   It happened on me so that I can't find the resource folder when I used the Spring.  Have a shot.

Comment: I tried both suggestions (and refreshed the project after that) but didn't help. Can't you remember what was changed in the IDE?

Comment: If I change "resources/css/app.css" to "../../resources/css/app.css" Eclipse finds the files, but then the webapp can't find these resources at runtime (in the browser)...There should be a trick for this to fix it I hope??

Or else I should relocate my resources folder, but that sounds more like a workaround then a real solution..